# electromagnetic losses at conductor interface at high frequencies??

Tags: electromagnetism, power, conductors

**Skin depth effect reminder**

When an electromagnetic wave arrives at a conductor interface of conductivity $\sigma$ , most of it is reflected back. Only a small fraction penetrates as an evanescent wave through a small distance $\delta$. This is known as the skin depth effect and the width of the skin depth can be approximated for low frequencies and strong conductors ($\sigma$>>$\epsilon\omega$) as :

$\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\mu\sigma f}} $     (1)

In the conductor, currents may arise in the skin depth volume to generate losses. These losses can be easily quantified in this case.

**Now let's increase the frequency to the IR/visible region for exemple:**

In this case the conductivity of the metal is supposed to drop according while increasing the frequency as given by the Drude model :

$\sigma(\omega)=\frac{\sigma_{0}}{1+j\omega\tau} $

From 1)(whose assumptions are not valid anymore) : the lower the conductivity, the wider the wave penetration.But the higher the frequency the smaller the value of $\delta$. A first question is :

***Does the skin depth $\delta$ has a minimum value for a given frequency???***

**Energetic aspect** :

The larger the skin depth, the larger the volume for currents hence more dissipation.
On the other hand, the lower the conductivity, the smaller the currents amplitudes(since $j=\sigma E$ ) hence less dissipation from Joule’s effect.

***So my question is how does the power losses evolve with frequency at a conductor interface??*** 
If a minimum is to be found in which region of the spectrum is this minimum found in respect to $\sigma_{0}$ and $\tau$ ??

Comment: My solid state physics is very rusty, but isn't that what surface plasmon resonances are?

Comment: surface plasmon indeed arises when the frequency is on the order of $\frac{1}{\tau} $.Though it doesnot explain what happens to the penetration of the wave inside the conductor and how the losses evolve along the frequencies.